# OleDB not saving changes on huge xlsx file

Tags: vb.net, oledb, rpa

I'm working with OleDB to perform massive insertions on a big xlsx file (about 170k rows). For some reason the file didn't change after every query, so I split up the operation in chunks of about 1700 inserts at once, so that it now takes 100 operations to finish the procedure.

After every bulk insert I close the connection and open it again to commit the changes. After the 28th bulk insert, however, OleDB stops committing the changes. The operations in memory are present (if I query to check how many rows should have been inserted vs how many rows have actually been inserted, everything seems fine); however, once the connection closes, the file isn't actually updated and the procedure fails silently -no error whatsoever is thrown. I couldn't find much documentation on this behavior, has anybody ever encountered a similar error?

Working with OleDB and big xlsx files is mandatory; I know it's bad, but it's not my choice and I can't do anything about it. Thanks guys for any help that may come.

THE CODE AS IT IS RIGHT NOW

```
moConnection = New OLEDBConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=""C:\something\something.xlsx"";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES""")
moConnection.Open();
Dim oCommand As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [table$] SELECT * FROM [anotherTable$] WHERE [stato] LIKE '%INVIATO%'", moConnection)
oCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
moConnection.Close()
moConnection.Dispose()
```

Splitting the bulk insert into smaller chunks is achieved via an additional WHERE clause on the id to get only a subset of the content.

Comment: You should post the code you're using. In both flavors.

Comment: @Jimi updated the original question with the code requested

Comment: You'll probably have more success loading ranges of values from a Worksheet (OleDb is ok-ish) and store the data in another using something like [EPPlus](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus). Define a range (e.g., `dim range = [Sheet].Cells["{StartCell}:{EndCell}"]`), then use the `[range].LoadFromArrays()` method to set the values. Excel works better like this. You could also try [SpreadsheetLight](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SpreadsheetLight/) (MIT License)

Comment: As mentioned in the original post, using OleDB is mandatory.